# Placeholder with toArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, updates, placeholder

I am a noob learning jQuery.
I have this Jquery code that works:

```
     $( "#sortable-4" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "highlight"});
```

And I have this JQuery code that works:

```
     update: function(event, ui) {
         var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
         $("#sortable-9").text (productOrder);
     }
```

but when I try to put it together like so:

```
   $(function() {
       $('#sortable-4').sortable({

           placeholder: "highlight";

          update: function(event, ui) {
             var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
             $("#sortable-9").text (productOrder);
          }
       });
    });
```

I get an error. Why can't I do the placeholder and update in one?

Comment: What error did you get? was it a syntax error? `placeholder: "highlight";` should be `placeholder: "highlight",`

Comment: Thanks! Coming from a rough JS background I was only trying semicolons, didn't think of commas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma after placeholder, not a semi-colon.

```
$(function() {
       $('#sortable-4').sortable({

           placeholder: "highlight",

          update: function(event, ui) {
             var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
             $("#sortable-9").text (productOrder);
          }
       });
    });
```

Comment: Arrrgh! So damn simple and it took me ages to try out before I put it on SO without luck. At least I wont be forgetting it in a hurry :)